# First flexbox child not growing into 2nd row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know there are quite the many flexbox issues on stackoverflow, and I've frequented many but none seem to fit my use case.

There are 2 issues.

1. The red box won't grow to the next div so the purple box doesnt sit flush to the right side
2. The content in the blue box grows based on its contents and the pager in the red box wont float to the bottom of the red box, WITHOUT moving the title and the list.

I'm attempting to make the red box fill the gap down to the red arrow shown in the attached image and the pager to float to the bottom of the container as well. Hovering over the blue box will make the height of the blue box grow out of convenience.

I've attached a jsfiddle. Below is an image illustrating the desired outcome from problem #1 plus the red box extension to the arrow.[image: Below is an image illustrating problem #1]

https://jsfiddle.net/abthss0h/1/

Below is the basic flex box parent row.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a job for a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), not flexbox. Flexbox is only suitable for items that are restricted to a single row or column.

Comment: Flexbox is one-dimensional layout scheme, even with wrapping lines, so it's impossible for a flex item to span several lines. But it's possible in Grid Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely possible with nested flexboxes and a change in the HTML to wrap 
 the second "column".

```css
.title {
  max-height: 82px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#blue:hover {
  height: 300px;
}

#purple {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 16.666%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-24 {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pager {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="red" class="col-4">
    <div class="title col-24">
      <h3>Title Here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-24">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pager">Pager</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id="blue">
      Hover to change height
    </div>
    <div id="purple">
      Placeholder
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div id="green" class="col-24">
    Placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to resolve problem #2 as well? This is great. Much appreciated.

Comment: Edited...just use a flex-column on the red div and `margin-top:auto` on the pager

Comment: You rock. Thanks so much.